# Responsive web CSS rules at 992px Chrome issues

Tags: css, google-chrome, responsive-design

Fairly newbie question, I'm currently using the **320andup template by Any Clarke** to make a responsive website.

All is going well except for quite a few CSS rules that don't seem to be picked up by the browser upon looking at the inspect element from **736px** media query on and upwards, it still just picks up the rules from base level(320 mobile) and/or the **480** and **600 px** specified widths.

No issues in Firefox, only in chrome. (the seemingly ignored attributes in chrome are commented below) I daren't check IE just yet, anyone have any answers / big fixes for this please?

e.g,

```
base level (320px)
.content { clear: both;margin: 10px auto;width: 92%;}     
ul.social li{text-align:right;list-style:none;}


@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {

ul.social li{text-align:right;list-style:none;}

.content {clear: both;margin: 100px auto;width: 92%;}

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {

ul.social li{ text-align:right; list-style:none; /*this ignored --> */display:inline;}

.content{ clear:both; /*this ignored --> */ margin-left:200px;}

}
```

the core 320andup file found here for details: https://github.com/malarkey/320andup/blob/master/css/320andup.css

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px)
```

means the screen needs to be a minimum width of 992px before the code is initiated. So the fact that 736px is not showing those does not surprise me (it does surprise me if FF was showing it, as you imply). This is because it should not engage those styles until the browser window is 992px wide (736px is too narrow). [See example](http://jsfiddle.net/VP9Yv/).

If you want them engaged earlier, then change the number (something like):

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 730px)
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more clearer in asking question, i understand styles will only apply after said stated query widths, what im trying to say is the styles written in 736px + and 992px + aren't detected in chrome, its only in firefox the styles work. I was wondering if it's webkits or some relatively simple Css fix/re-write or whether theres a browser bug that needs hacking.

Comment: @AlexanderWilliamMoreton--can you post a test case of your basic html and css on [http://jsfiddle.net/](http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can see what you are seeing?